# Difference between php-cli and php-fpm mode in regard to APC/APCu

Tags: php, apc

The thought start from this question under `php-cli` mode:

[PHP apc/apcu cache do not keep intermediate result while shmop do, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770197/php-apc-apcu-cache-do-not-keep-intermediate-result-while-shmop-do-why)

In this case, `APC/APCu` do not cache the intermediate result.

However, `APC/APCu` do cache the intermediate result just as the `shmop` when under `php-fpm` mode. So, what's the difference between `php-cli` and `php-fpm` when in regards to `APC/APCu`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

php-fpm ist running in its own process all the time. It can use apc because it uses continuously the ram over several requests. The memory is only released through the garbage collector or if you kill the fpm process. But the a CLI process lives only for one command and when its finished the memory is released. So apc cannot store any data over severel cli calls because it allocates new memory in the ram each call.

Comment: what about normal php-cgi  mode?

Comment: Its not possible to use APC in normal php cgi. Using fpm or the apache php module is the only way i know to use apc.